# How to remove default botstrap css applies on my custom theme?

Tags: css, magento2.3.1

I created my own theme which depends on Luma theme. But I have an issue to applies some CSS such _reboot.scss , _grid.scss so how I can remove this?

Answer (score 0):

By default, Magento uses Less for themes styling.  It seems you are trying yo compile sass css fiels.
You have creat your own theme from scratch and use an alternative preprocessor. Visit below link to configure and use the Gulp task runner and the gulp-sass package for the Sass preprocessor or you can use less css instead of sass.

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/frontend-dev-guide/css-topics/gulp-sass.html

Comment: Ok so can i remove that css for my theme or not ?

Comment: If you do not need  those css then you can remove it.

Comment: yes but where are open that path  like https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/scss/mixins/_grid.scss  so how can i remove sir

Comment: You are using cdn url of bootstrap so you can not remove it. you have to overwrite css

Comment: but where is it that sir?